# How to prove $abcd≤\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4}4$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, proof-writing

By expanding the expression $(a-b)^2$, prove that $ab≤\frac{a^2+b^2}2$ for all real numbers a and b.

I've managed to state that $(a-b)^2$ is positive for all real numbers and show that this is true. However, it is the next part where I have no clue what to do :

Deduce further that $abcd≤\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4}4$ for all real numbers a, b, c and d.

I know it's possible to say that the arithmetic mean > geometric mean. However, is there another way I can prove this using the results from part 1?

Thanks.

Comment: This is AM-GM inequality ...

Comment: Is there a way of deducing further from part 1 that the statement is true though? We haven't been taught about the AM GM inequality and the question is phrased as though it requires doing an expansion similar to part 1. Thanks

Comment: Yes, [of course](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) ...

Comment: But in this particular case, apply what you learned twice ... I hope you see the pattern. $\frac{a^4+b^4}{2} \geq ...$ and $\frac{c^4+d^4}{2} \geq ...$ and then again

Comment: Many apologies for being so slow, I'm confused as to how to go about proving the AM-GM inequality for 4 numbers?

Comment: Which part of the Wikipedia article you didn't understand? There is a proof [by induction there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Proofs_by_induction) for example ...

Comment: You couls start from $abcd$ and notice it is $(ab)(cd)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You proved $ab \le \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}$ (AM-GM for 2 numbers). This also implies $a^2 b^2 \le \frac{a^4 + b^4}{2}$ and $c^2 d^2 \le \frac{c^4 + d^4}{2}$. Adding together and dividing by two yields
$$\frac{a^2 b^2 + c^2 d^2}{2}\le \frac{a^4 + b^4 + c^4 + d^4}{4}.$$
Can you apply the AM-GM inequality for 2 numbers once more to finish?

Comment: You spoiled the educational process :)

Comment: Thanks so much, applied the AM-GM inequality to ab and cd to yield $(ab-cd)^2=a^2*b^2 + c^2*d^2 - 2abcd$